# dataview rowfilter LIKE * works not exactly

Tags: c#

My `dataview` has 1 column named `RecordType` (Primary key in SQL, type `varchar(18)`), which has 3 records {"NH", "NTH", "XH"}.

Now, I want to filter data which starts at "N", by coding:

`( myDataView.RowFilter = "RecordType LIKE 'N*'")`, but just 1 record was returned ({"NTH"})

Exactly result must has 2 records ({"NH", "NTH"}).

Please how can I correct this?

Comment: Try `myDataView.RowFilter = "RecordType LIKE 'N*'"`

Comment: How are you retrieving the records? Perhaps you have an error and are only retrieving the first row.

Comment: Hi Eric J!"How are you retrieving the records"

Comment: Thanks Jim Hewitt, your code is right, but the result is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and it works:

```
myDataView.RowFilter = "RecordType LIKE 'N*'";
```

It will return "NH" and "NTH".

Comment: A little hard to tell if this is the solution without seeing more of his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN");
        DataView myDataView = new DataView();
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("RecordType");
        myDataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { myDataTable.Columns["RecordType"] };
        DataRow dr = myDataTable.NewRow();
        dr["RecordType"] = "NH";
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = myDataTable.NewRow();
        dr["RecordType"] = "NTH";
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = myDataTable.NewRow();
        dr["RecordType"] = "XH";
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        myDataView = myDataTable.DefaultView;
        myDataView.Table.Locale = new CultureInfo("en-US");// Without this line, the filter on dataview not exactly always!!!
        myDataView.RowFilter = "RecordType LIKE 'N*'";

        for (int i = 0; i < myDataView.Count; i++)
            MessageBox.Show(myDataView[i]["RecordType"].ToString());
    }
```

Thank everyone so much for your time. I found that, when we set the CurrentCulture of system, it then affects the filtering and sorting of dataview.

To solve it, we must assign the locate of dataview again by default value:

myDataView.Table.Locale = new CultureInfo("en-US");

I think so. Have any other good idea?