# This code block takes too much time to execute C#

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

```
            OleDbConnection connection;
            OleDbCommand command;
   

            string commandText = "SELECT pali,sinhala FROM [Sheet3$]";
            string oledbConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=Book2.xlsx;" +
            "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";";
            connection = new OleDbConnection(oledbConnectString);
            command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            connection.Close();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Excel sheet have 20 000 rows(UTF8 unicode). even my Lap 8gb ram i3 it takes like 8secs to load. Is their any way to store these data?  I want to create a Dictionary(not csharp dictionary).

Comment: What happened when you tried to profile the code? What happened when you tried using a smaller input (maybe it takes a long time to set up the OLE stuff, and the size of the data doesn't matter very much)?

Comment: Did you measure what is the slow part? Is it the excel reading code or filling a DataGridView with 20000 records?

Comment: up to da.Fill(dt);  is going ok.

Comment: da.Fill(dt);   this is the slow part.

Comment: you saying text file is better than excel file?

Comment: no please tell me a better way

Comment: I literally told you a better way. Put the entries in JSON and read it from there rather than Excel. How long does it take?

Comment: @mjwills it takes time to serialize

Comment: How _long_ does it take to serialise? Clearly it will take time. It isn't magic. How _long_ does it take?

Comment: takes time and error 'Invalid JSON primitive:

Comment: OK, so the file isn't a valid JSON file. You need to make it a valid JSON file.

Comment: @mjwills  yes it is fast.less than a sec it came.  now I have to display one column only in datagrideview and need to search objects by WHERE LIKE from deserialized object list.

Comment: Go back and check the earlier suggestion I made in the earlier question. Or read https://stackoverflow.com/a/38005258/34092 .

Comment: @mjwills to load from json to app takes like 1.5 secs. others are totally ok. I did the linq query correctly. every thing ok. thanks alot for your help mjwills. I also have to check with low performance PC too.again thank alot mjwills.